# Debugging in Appcelerator Studio

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

Debugging doesn't work for me in Appcelerator Studio.
When I change to Debug mode the application doesn't stop at my breakpoints.

I already tried to reinstall Studio or changing the node.js version. Nothing worked so far. I have this problem for nearly over 2 years now, so I also tried different SDK versions.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: You can try asking this question on TiSlack; There are amazing people in the community, and you're more likely to get an answer there!
PS: I never tried debugging in the studio. I always used logs for debugging.